# Auto load fancybox using .trigger('click')

Tags: javascript, triggers, fancybox, autoload

I was just wondering if you could please help. I am trying to get the
fancybox to load automatically once the page is rendered. However, I
got this error message 't is undefined' at line 18 (/js/fancybox/
jquery.fancybox-1.3.3.pack.js). At the moment, I am using jquery
version 1.4.2

```
<a href="#container" id="profile">Click me</a>

<div style="display:none">
<div id="container">Fancybox Content Here .... </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#profile').fancybox().trigger('click');

});

</script>
```

The funny thing is if I take the line below and run it in firebug
console then it WORKS!.  Not sure what did I do wrong here. Your helps
would be grateful.

```
 $('#profile').fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I got the same problem. Testing with the unpacked version, i got "loading is undefined" in line 36 (fancybox 1.3.4). So I called "$.fancybox.init();" before triggering and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Nope th reason is because the `fancybox.js` is included twice this is the file that has the core of fancy box

Answer (score 0):

I've managed with the similar case in the way like this:

```
$(".some_wrapper").on('click', function(){
    var lnk = $(this).find("a").first();
    if (hr && ~cls.indexOf("fancybox-a")) {
        $.fancybox(lnk);
    }
});
```