# t is undefined Line 18 Jquery fancybox 1.3.4

Tags: jquery, tabs, fancybox, undefined

We are using tabs and fancybox on same page. not sure about if the order of js lib include matters.

Answer (score 7):

Try calling "$.fancybox.init();" before triggering ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439576/auto-load-fancybox-using-triggerclick)).

Also, try verifying that "fancybox.js" is not called twice for some reason.

Comment: OMG.......You saved me Man!. I changed the jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js to Master Layout. Problem solved.

Comment: Happy to help! Glad it solved for someone.