# Fancybox error : t is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

```
    function Share(url,a) { var url; var a; $.fancybox(
    { 'href': 'add.php' },
    {
        frameWidth: 750,
        frameHeight: 430,
        overlayShow: true,
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: 'url='+url+'&a='+a
        }
    }
);}
```

fancybox is working only first page , another pages with not work

i using 1.3.4 version and calling Share function is :

```
<div class="Share"><a onclick="Share('<?=$url?>','<?=$a?>');return false;"href="#"><img src="play.gif" border="0"></img></a></div>
```

i use a fancybox for search results,next page function is here :

```
function page(p) {var serialized = $('form#searc').serialize(); $('#p').html('<img src="spinner.gif" border="0">');$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'search.php',data:serialized+'&p='+p,success: function(pg) {$('.Results').html(pg);}});}
```

calling from

```
<div class="nxt"><a onclick="page('<?=$p+1;?>');return false;"href="#" >next</a></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4439576/584420?

Comment: If you want to get help then you would need to provide more information like: what version of fancybox are you using? ... how do you call your Share function?... etc., etc., ... or provide a link with a sample of the issue.

Comment: i solved the problem,reason is fancybox.js in included file

Comment: Just to clarify a little more.  I had this same issue with a calendar widget which called different months and years via ajax.  I originally had all the includes for fancybox on both my main page and the page called via ajax.  The only file you need to remove from the page called via ajax is `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js` or whatever you may have renamed it, but you still need the other includes such as `fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css`. on the ajax page.  Or atleast I did.  I just felt the solution wasn't 100% clear and wanted to add.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem in fancybox where second click was not working for light box. I was getting error :-
TypeError: t is undefined
What i try is:-
please set fancybox type as iframe and set its height & width accordingly.. it works for me.

```
jQuery.fancybox({
'href' :URL,
'type':'iframe' 
});
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

this error show when fancybox call before its file load,
you can call fancybox after page load:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { //call fancybox here });
```